# Sorting a link list

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [148. Sort List](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/description/)

> Given the `head` of a linked list, return the list after sorting it in ascending order.

I am trying to do it in a recursive way before trying something smarter, as I am learning to handle data structures.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var sortList = function(head) {
    let previousNode = head
    if(!head){
        return head
    }
    let node = head.next
    if(!node){
        return head
    }
    let start = head
    let previousNode1 = head
    function sortList1(node, previousNode){
        if(node.next == null){
            return start
        }
        let temp = node.next;
        if(traverseFromHead(node)){
            start = node
        }
        previousNode1 = node
        return sortList1(temp, node)
    }
    return sortList1(node, previousNode)

    function traverseFromHead(node){
        let myPosition = start
        let inserted = false
        if(start.val > node.val){
            previousNode1.next = node.next
            node.next = start
            console.log("found in head excahange", node)
            return node;
        }
        let myprevious2 = start
        while(myPosition.next != null){
            if(myPosition.val>=node.val){
                console.log("before check start was", start, "with position at", myPosition.val, "for point", node.val, "my previous is", myprevious2.val)
                let temp = node.next
                myprevious2.next = node
                node.next = myPosition
                // previousNode1.next = temp
                console.log("after update start is", start, "with position at", myPosition.val, "for point", node.val)
                return null
            }
            myprevious2 = myPosition;
            myPosition = myPosition.next
            
        }
        return false
    }
    
};
```

I am not able to get it working correctly; it must be I am doing something wrong by logic or by concept

For instance for the linked list 4→2→3→0 the expected output would be 0→2→3→4, but my code produces 2→0.

Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your program yourself](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/11107541)? Doing some debugging can help you provide a [mre].

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried to implement insertion sort.

There are these issues that prevent it from working correctly:

- The base case of the recursive function is not correct. With `if(node.next == null)` you are stopping too early. It could well be that this tail node should be moved elsewhere in the list, yet this node's value is not compared with anything. The stop condition really should be `node == null`.
- `previousNode1 = node` is not always correctly identifying the previous node.  If the call to `traverseFromHead` *moved* `node` to elsewhere in the list, then `previousNode1` should not change, because what used to be the node before `node`, will now have become the node before the *next* node you want to process. For the same reason the second argument you pass in the recursive call is most often wrong: `sortList1(temp, node)`.

  It is a bit overwhelming to have that many variants of `previousNodeXX` variables. I would suggest to at least eliminate this `previousNode1` and continue to work with `previousNode`, passing it also as argument to `traverseFromHead`.  So call it as `traverseFromHead(node, previousNode)` and make sure you pass the correct second argument to `sortList1`. There are two cases to distinguish:

  When `node` wasn't moved, then `sortList1(temp, node)` is correct, but when `node` was moved, it should be `sortList1(temp, previousNode)`. You can make the distinction with a conditional operator:

  ```
  sortList1(temp, previousNode.next != node ? previousNode : node)
  ```
- `traverseFromHead` only removes the node from its current position in the `if` case, but forgets to do the same in the more general case. In the general case, the node *is* inserted, but `previousNode.next` is not adapted, meaning you now have two nodes whose `next` property point to `node`. There are several ways to do it right. I would suggest to perform the node-removal action in *all* cases before doing anyting else. You could place the code for node extraction *before* the `if` statement so that it always happens:

  ```
  previousNode.next = node.next // <-- should always happen
  if(start.val > node.val){
       //...
  ```
- I can understand why you put `previousNode1.next = temp` in comments inside the loop. Most often this needs to happen, *but not* when `node` didn't move! To solve this dilemma, perform a quick exit when `node` is already at its correct position (in comparison with `previousNode`). So at the top of the function do:

  ```
  if (node.val >= previousNode.val) return null;
  ```

  Now you can be sure that `node` *will* move.
- `traverseFromHead` has a strange `while` condition. With the above corrections in place, this `while` condition can just be the opposite of the `if` condition, so that you can deal with the insertion *after* the loop:

  ```
  while (myPosition.val < node.val)
      myprevious2 = myPosition;
      myPosition = myPosition.next
  }
  ```

Here is your code with those corrections:

```
var sortList = function(head) {
    let previousNode = head
    if(!head){
        return head
    }
    let node = head.next
    if(!node){
        return head
    }
    let start = head
    
    function sortList1(node, previousNode){
        if(node == null){ // Corrected base case
            return start
        }
        let temp = node.next;
        if(traverseFromHead(node, previousNode)){ // Pass the second argument
            start = node
        }
        // Depending on whether node was moved, the node that precedes temp is different
        return sortList1(temp, previousNode.next != node ? previousNode : node)
    }
    
    return sortList1(node, previousNode)

    function traverseFromHead(node, previousNode){ // Second argument
        if (node.val >= previousNode.val) return null; // Quick exit for trivial case
        previousNode.next = node.next // Always first extract the node
        if(start.val >= node.val){ // Equal is also good, so >=
            node.next = start
            return node;
        }
        let myPosition = start.next // Can start iteration at second node
        let myprevious2 = start
        while (myPosition.val < node.val) { // Look for the insertion spot
            myprevious2 = myPosition;
            myPosition = myPosition.next
        }
        // Now perform the re-insertion
        myprevious2.next = node
        node.next = myPosition
        return null
    }    
};
```

### Other remarks

Insertion sort is not the most efficient among sorting algorithms, and for linked lists it is quite easy to implement better performing sorting algorithms.

See for instance [Merge sort on linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649727/how-to-alphabetically-sort-a-linked-list-in-javascript/69651397#69651397)

I have here adapted that solution for the LeetCode challenge (spoiler):

> `var sortList = function(head) {
>      if (!head || !head.next) return head; // Nothing to sort
>      // Find last node of first half
>      let tail = head;
>      for (let fast = tail.next; fast?.next; fast = fast.next.next) {
>          tail = tail.next;
>      }
>      // Split list into two halves
>      let head2 = tail.next;
>      tail.next = null;
>      // Recursively sort the two shorter lists
>      head = sortList(head);
>      head2 = sortList(head2);
>      // Merge the two sorted lists
>      if (head.val > head2.val) [head2, head] = [head, head2];
>      tail = head;
>      while (tail.next && head2) {
>        if (tail.next.val > head2.val) [head2, tail.next] = [tail.next, head2];
>        tail = tail.next;
>      }
>      tail.next ??= head2;
>      return head;
>  };`

Comment: thank you so so much !! i am learning so much

Answer (score 0):

MergeSort naturally fits for linked lists.

In merge sort you consider that merging 2 size one lists is trivial (just put the higher head value after the lower one).

Extending that idea, if you have two already sorted lists, then it's easy to merge them as well. Just create a new list where you add the highest of both lists till both lists are empty.

So you can do a merge sort by creating first 2 lists of size 1. (ie. the first 2 elements of your list) Then merging them.

Then create a second list of size 2 (by merging 2 of size 1).

And continue until you have merged the entire original list into a sorted list.

**Recursion**

To implement this recursively first write a merge function that given two sorted lists merges them by preserving the sort order.

Then do the following to implement sort:

1. If your list is empty, then return the list as your result
2. Now merge the first element with sort(rest of the list)

Comment: I saw this solution in discussion but i want to know what did i do wrong !! I am learning recusron and link list !!

Comment: I added an explanation on how to do the recursive part

Comment: I don't love your Linked List implementation. It would be better if you just defined a Node class and a LinkedList class to implement the list. Then you can have a sort method on it.